# Confused with Python's import intrapackage references

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

I run Python 2.7.6. I am having a problem with creating a package. The following is a MWE:

I have the following files:

```
run.py
    MyPackage/
        __init__.py
        Father_class.py
        Son_class.py
        class1.py
```

With the following content:

**init**.py

```
__all__ = ['Father_class', 'Son_class', 'class1']
```

run.py

```
from MyPackage import Father_class, Son_class
```

Father_class.py:

```
class Daddy(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello=1
```

Son_class.py:

```
from MyPackage import *
# alternatively I tried: from MyPackage import class1, Father_class
class Sonny(Daddy):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Daddy, self).__init__()
        self.bye=class1.MyClass1()
        #alternatively I tried self.bye=MyClass1()
```

class1.py:

```
class MyClass1(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.life=1
```

When running run.py I get:

```
    self.bye=class1.MyClass1()
NameError: global name 'class1' is not defined
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only import modules relatively to where you import from unless what you import is available in `site-packages` globally or in a virtualenv. Therefore module `a` in `Package/a` cannot import module `b` in `package/b` by importing `package` and navigating from there, but it can import `b` directly (being on the same level):

For Son_class.py use:

```
from class1 import MyClass1
from Father_class import Daddy

class Sonny(Daddy):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Daddy, self).__init__()
        self.bye=MyClass1()
```

Otherwise, it is advisable to be specific in imports and import exactly the definitions you need: this will be of enormous help as soon as anythings needs to be refactored. If you were to explicitly write down the import path you would also receive a more sensible error message.

Answer (score 2):

Oleg S.'s answer is probably the best way to go, since it avoids the cluttering `import *`.

Just FYI, the reason `from MyPackage import *` in `Son_class.py` probably isn't working as you expect it to, is that you can only import from `MyPackage` objects that are defined in `__init__.py`

If you change your `__init__.py` to have

```
import Father_class
import Son_class
import class1
```

your example should work as is.

As an aside, [convention states](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) that python module names are lower case.

Comment: Ooops, I mischanged the names convention. Cheers.

Comment: I am confused about your comment on import. Shall I include in `__init__.py` the classes that I want to import from outside the package, from inside or both?

Comment: @JesusMartinezGarcia You can do either, it's mostly a matter of personal preference. Not including them makes things clearer for anyone inspecting your package (i.e.:`dir`), and you can still import modules as `import package.module`.

Comment: sounds reasonable. Thanks!